# Returning multiple Dates in a "dd-MMM-yy" format after concatenating them

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to concatenate multiple Dates in one cell in Google Sheets. I have used a custom function GetColoredCellValue( ) that return the cell values (dates) based on its background color. And this new custom function ConcatIfDates( ) will take the results from the GetColoredCellValue( ) and concatenate them into one cell.

So in google sheet, I'd use the custom functions like this : `=ConcatIfDates(GetColoredValue(COLUMN(A2),ROW(A2),COLUMN(F2)))`

And the result should get me like:

> `27-Jun-22, 13-Oct-22, 27-Jun-22`

```
function ConcatIfDates(input){
  if (input.length>1) {
    var newArr = input.map(row => {
      return row.map(date => {
        var date = new Date();
        return date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+1", "dd-MMM-yy");
      });
    });
    return newArr.join();
  } else {
      return input[0];
  }
}
```

My script above keeps joining the first date repeated like this:

> `27-Sep-23,27-Sep-23,27-Sep-23`

I want the dates in "dd-MMM-yy" format so I've used Utilities.formatDate otherwise it gives this very long format if i return the date without using the date format.

> `Mon Jun 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0630 (GMT+06:30),Thu Oct 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0630 (GMT+06:30),Mon Jun 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0630 (GMT+06:30)`

I've attached a screenshot of an example sheet i made to give u a rough idea.[image]

I just google stuff and am experimenting without properly learning JavaScript so my script might not make sense I apologize in advance! Thank you for taking time to read this post!

Comment: With `var date = new Date();` you overwrite the date that you just read from the `input` row. So you never look at the real data. Probably you *intended* to pass `date` as argument: `date = new Date(date);` But whether that works as expected depends on what exactly `date` is. Is it a `Date` instance? Is it a string? Is it a number?

Comment: Is this your desired [Sample output](https://imgur.com/a/rsg3EF6)?

Comment: @Serenity yes that is the output I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what getColoredValue() returns but presumably it's array of Dates().  So how about this:

```
function ConcatIfDates(input=["1/1/2023","2/1/2021","3/1/2023"]){
  if (input.length>1) {
    var newArr = input.map(x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(x), "GMT+1", "dd-MMM-yy"));
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
    return newArr.join();//this returns ["01-Jan-23","01-Feb-21","01-Mar-23"]
  } else {
      return input[0];
  }
}
```